# auto generate number is not working at the start of new year

Tags: php, mysql, auto-generate

I am trying to generate my bill no in following sequence in php
L5- 0124-0001  (where L5 is company name, 01 representing month and 24 representing year, where as last four digit is for serial number) , I was using this code since October 2023, everything was working fine until end of year 2023, but as today year 2024 start, its stop working, (company name is correctly display, year month as well but last four digit are not incremented when new bill need to be generated. it remain 0001 for all the bills, where as it should  L5-0124-0002 and so on ........ below is the code

```
$CI = "L5"; //Example only
$CIcnt = strlen($CI);
$offset = $CIcnt + 6;

// Get the current month and year as two-digit strings 
$month = date("m"); // e.g. 09 
$year = date("y"); // e.g. 23  

// Get the last bill number from the database 
$query = "SELECT patientno FROM iap2 ORDER BY patientno DESC LIMIT 1"; 
$result = mysqli_query($con,$query); 
// Use mysqli_fetch_assoc() to get an associative array of the fetched row 
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result); 
// Use $row[‘patientno’] to get the last bill number 
$lastid = $row['patientno'];     

// Check if the last bill number is empty or has a different month or year
if(empty($lastid) || (substr($lastid, $CIcnt + 1, 2) != $month) || (substr($lastid, $CIcnt + 3, 2) != $year)) { 
    // Start a new sequence with 0001 
    $number = "$CI-$month$year-0001"; 
} else { 
    // Increment the last four digits by one 
    $idd = substr($lastid, $offset); // e.g. 0001 
    
    $id = str_pad($idd + 1, 4, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT); // e.g. 0002 
    $number = "$CI-$month$year-$id"; 
}
```

Comment: What's the value of `$lastid`?

Comment: when database was empty than it was 0, and when record one is entered than lastid value is L5-1023-0001 and so on. i thnk year is changed today, thats why it stop  incrementing it

Comment: I don't want to know the possibilities of this value. What is the current value? If it is L5-1023-0001, then $number should be L5-0124-0001, which is expected. Or do you expect it to be L5-0124-0002?

Comment: I think the problem is your SQL - you are asking it to sort by `patientno` highest to lowest, but `L5-0124-0001` will end up _below_ `L5-1023-0007` (example), because 0124 is less than 1023. Thus, it always sees the last entry of last year at the top. Probably too late now, but you should have used yymm rather than mmyy in your format.

Comment: @Nic gris yes u r right , i have to put years before month, it will onyl solve the issue

Comment: Relevant reading: [Defining Composite Key with Auto Increment in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18120088/2943403) and [Mysql: autoincrement field in composite primary key for each unique combination of other fields](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18948983/2943403) and [Composite Primary Keys and auto increment? What is a good practices?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37305739/2943403) and [auto increment on composite primary key](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29431920/2943403)

Answer (score 2):

Your code is severely flawed. The way the number is built, the alphabetical and the chronological orders are not the same. So when you fetch the "last" number, you get a number from December 2023, not from January 2024, because `1223` is greater (as a string) than `0124`.

You could change the `ORDER BY` to fix it. But then the query would be unoptimized (MySQL would need to scan the entire table), and, more importantly, the code would still be flawed because it's sensitive to race condition. If 2 users try to create a bill at the same time, they may end up with the same number.

A correct way to generate numbers is to use a dedicated counter table. When you need to get a new number:

- Lock the table
- Retrieve the last used counter for the current year and month (and the company, in case you can have several in the same database)
- Increment it and update the table
- Unlock the table
- Use the counter to insert the new bill

Comment: yes correct solution is putting year before month,  and there is no chance that 2 user can enter same number as I am using this code at back end  with processing file

Comment: @stu if you do not take and implement the advice in this answer, you will be in for many future headaches. The only additional note that I'd like to give is that your identifying values should actually be separated into 3 or 4 columns instead.  A db is not responsible for holding user-ready values; it is your code between data storage and data presentation which is responsible for assembling and padding the identifier.  I would not make such a cumbersome task for myself.